# How to delete objects inside Widget in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget

I have `MainWindow` form which has `Widget` inside. And I have another `Widget` class (`promoted to MainWindow)` which has only DockWidget inside. In `MainWindow` I am opening new one and placing into `Widget`. However when I close `DockWidget` from `close(cross"X")` button. Inside my `MainWindow` it is not cleaning..

Sorry for my bad english better to paste my code here:

```
    qDebug() << ui->widget->layout()->count();

    QueryWidget *lQueryWidget = new QueryWidget(this);

    ui->widget->layout()->addWidget(lQueryWidget);
```

So in everytime although I close `DockWindow(lQueryWidget)`, `layout()->count()` never decrease. I tried to delete everything inside layout like ;

```
QList<QObject*> child = ui->widget->layout()->children();

foreach (QObject *var, child)
{
    delete var;
}
```

But it never enters foreach loop.. If you check image below you will see that there is something above DockWidget, but it is not visible.. Could you please help me how can I solve this issue ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of deleting `QObject::children()` you should consider using `QLayout` methods, like `count()`, `itemAt()` and `removeItem()`. Also, one thing I cannot understand - are you placing `MainWindow` inside of `MainWindow`?

Comment: @Amartel QueryWidget promoted in MainWindow Widget object

Comment: why do you have two QMainwindow? Why do yo promote that widget to a QMainwindow? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @UmNyobe I have 1 QMainWindow and 2 QWidget class.. I create 2 Widget inside QMainWindow and promote QWidgets to QMainWindow... I am trying to seperate MainWindow with widgets(which has DockWidgets)

Answer (score 0):

To make dockable widget you should use

```
QDockWidget::setWidget(QWidget * widget)
```

The widget will be deleted when the dock widget is deleted.
You should not manipulate the dock widget layout.

Comment: It sounds good, should I write it inside QueryWidget class or MainWindow ?